# Where does this space comes from? CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been playing both with Chrome and Firefox Dev Tools, changing the display mode, changing the height, the line height, checking padding and margin but I cannot understand where does that space come from. Where do that 16 pixels come from and why the tool doesn't show its origin?

https://jsfiddle.net/Revious/216xt0u8/1/

The real page: https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b1-tiamina/

[image]

```css
div.my_shortcode_list {
  column-count: 2;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.entry-content table.my_shortcode_list tr:hover td,
.entry-content table.my_shortcode_list:hover {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.entry-content table.my_shortcode_list tr td {
  padding: 0;
}

ul.my_shortcode_list {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.my_shortcode_list li {
  line-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.list li {
  background: url("https://bradfrost.github.com/this-is-responsive/patterns/images/icon_arrow_right.png") no-repeat 97% 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  display: table-row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.li-img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*width: 30%;*/
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.li-img img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.li-img img {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}

.li-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  /*width: 70%;*/
}

ol.nicelist,
ul.nicelist {
  /* counter-reset: li; */
  /* list-style: none; */
  /* padding: 0; */
  /* text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); */
  margin: 1.2em 0 1.2em 1em;
}

ol.nicelist li,
ul.nicelist li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  margin: .6em 0;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  font-size: 0.94em;
}

ol.nicelist li:before,
ul.nicelist li:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  top: 20px;
  margin-top: -17px;
  background: #4db2ec;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  line-height: 26px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 28px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nicelist" id="DIV_1">
  <h3 id="H3_2"><span id="SPAN_3">Lista delle principali vitamine</span></h3>
  <ul class="nicelist" id="UL_4">
    <li id="LI_5">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamine-del-gruppo-b/" id="A_6">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_7">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamine-del-gruppo-b-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamine del gruppo B" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_8">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_9">Vitamine del gruppo B </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_10">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b5/" id="A_11">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_12">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b5-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B5" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_13">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_14">Vitamina B5 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_15">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/piridossina-vitamina-b6/" id="A_16">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_17">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b6-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B6" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_18">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_19">Vitamina B6 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_20">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b8/" id="A_21">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_22">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b8-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B8" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_23">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_24">Vitamina B8 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_25">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b12/" id="A_26">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_27">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b12-alta-bassa-funzioni-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B12" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_28">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_29">Vitamina B12 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_30">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/acido-folico-tutto-quello-che-dovete-sapere/" id="A_31">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_32">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/acido-folico-150x150.jpg" alt="Acido Folico" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_33">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_34">Acido Folico </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_35">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-d/" id="A_36">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_37">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/vitamina-d-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina D" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_38">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_39">Vitamina D </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the margin on your `li` - margin: .6em 0

Answer (score 3):

I do not yet know why, but the space is where the text will naturally be rendered without `display: table-cell` on the `.li-img` and `.li-text`.

It *could* be because a set of [anonymous boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) will be automatically rendered around the **cell** but I do not have any hard evidence this is the cause.

Replacing `display: table-cell` with `display: inline-block` on `.li-img` and `.li-text`, removing the `margin-bottom: 21px` from the `<img>` and adding `display: inline-block` on the `<a>` removes the phantom space and shows the children correctly contained by the `<a>` in the Chrome DevTools.

Comment: I don't think any of the current answers (including mine) explains _exactly why_ this is happening but altering the `display` for the child elements and updating the `<a>` from default `display: inline` to `inline-block` seems to make the DevTools correctly show the `<a>` encapsulating the children

Comment: I've come to this one a bit late, but it puzzled me for a bit. You're on the right lines. The key to understanding this is that because the <a> element is inline and contains the table cells, the outermost anonymous table object generated is an [inline-table](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#ref-for-value-def-inline④) box. Because that's inline, the box of the <a> element has content and can't collapse to nothing, so its height is based on one line of text and the font metrics as per [CSS 2.2 Section 10.6.1.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#inline-non-replaced)

Comment: @Alohci ah yes, this is the part I was missing - nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It's the line-height of the link element. You can set it to zero by adding `line-height: 0` to the rule for the `li` elements which are addressed by `ol.nicelist li, ul.nicelist li`.

```css
div.my_shortcode_list {
  column-count: 2;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.entry-content table.my_shortcode_list tr:hover td,
.entry-content table.my_shortcode_list:hover {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.entry-content table.my_shortcode_list tr td {
  padding: 0;
}

ul.my_shortcode_list {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.my_shortcode_list li {
  line-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.list li {
  background: url("https://bradfrost.github.com/this-is-responsive/patterns/images/icon_arrow_right.png") no-repeat 97% 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  display: table-row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.li-img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*width: 30%;*/
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.li-img img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.li-img img {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}

.li-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  /*width: 70%;*/
}

ol.nicelist,
ul.nicelist {
  /* counter-reset: li; */
  /* list-style: none; */
  /* padding: 0; */
  /* text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); */
  margin: 1.2em 0 1.2em 1em;
}

ol.nicelist li,
ul.nicelist li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  margin: .6em 0;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  font-size: 0.94em;
  line-height: 0;
}

ol.nicelist li:before,
ul.nicelist li:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  top: 20px;
  margin-top: -17px;
  background: #4db2ec;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  line-height: 26px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 28px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nicelist" id="DIV_1">
  <h3 id="H3_2"><span id="SPAN_3">Lista delle principali vitamine</span></h3>
  <ul class="nicelist" id="UL_4">
    <li id="LI_5">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamine-del-gruppo-b/" id="A_6">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_7">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamine-del-gruppo-b-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamine del gruppo B" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_8">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_9">Vitamine del gruppo B </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_10">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b5/" id="A_11">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_12">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b5-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B5" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_13">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_14">Vitamina B5 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_15">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/piridossina-vitamina-b6/" id="A_16">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_17">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b6-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B6" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_18">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_19">Vitamina B6 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_20">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b8/" id="A_21">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_22">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b8-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B8" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_23">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_24">Vitamina B8 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_25">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b12/" id="A_26">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_27">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vitamina-b12-alta-bassa-funzioni-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina B12" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_28">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_29">Vitamina B12 </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_30">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/acido-folico-tutto-quello-che-dovete-sapere/" id="A_31">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_32">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/acido-folico-150x150.jpg" alt="Acido Folico" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_33">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_34">Acido Folico </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_35">
      <a href="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-d/" id="A_36">
        <div class="li-img" id="DIV_37">
          <img src="https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/vitamina-d-150x150.jpg" alt="Vitamina D" class="td-animation-stack-type0-2" id="IMG_38">
        </div>
        <div class="li-text" id="DIV_39">Vitamina D </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me understanding why it doesn't work on my real website? I'm getting mad... https://wordpress-217146-992662.cloudwaysapps.com/vitamina-b1-tiamina/

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the styles of your li's:

```
ol.nicelist li, ul.nicelist li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    margin: .6em 0;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    font-size: 0.94em;
}
```

You can see there is a margin applied of .6em 0;

This is what creates the gap between the list items.

As for the anchor you have highlighted you need to set this to be display block so it takes into account the contents when creating the size measured in the DOM.